# Plot The Area Of $Im(\frac{z-1}{z+1})=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$Im(\frac{z-1}{z+1})=0$

$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=0$

$\frac{x-1+yi}{x+1-yi}=0$

$\frac{x-1+yi}{x+1-yi}\cdot \frac{x-1+yi}{x+1+yi}=0$

$\frac{x^2-1+y^2}{(x+1)^2+y^2}=0$

So

${x^2+y^2}=1$

which is circle of radius $1$?

Comment: How did you get $(x-1+yi)^2=x^2-1+y^2$.It should be $(x-1)^2+2iy(x-1)-y^2$.

Comment: Even before that... you are supposed to solve Im(something)=0, not something=0.

Comment: @Did Even *before* that... the denominator is wrong, should be $\,x+1\color{red}{+}yi\,$ instead.

Comment: @dxiv True (I missed this one...).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:   using that $\,w - \overline w = 2i \operatorname{Im}(w)\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
2i\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac{z-1}{z+1} - \frac{\bar z-1}{\bar z+1} &= \frac{(z-1)(\bar z+1)-(z+1)(\bar z -1)}{|z+1|^2} \\
 &= \frac{\bcancel{|z|^2}+z-\bar z-\cancel{1}-(\bcancel{|z|^2}-z+\bar z - \cancel{1})}{|z+1|^2} \\
 &= \frac{2(z-\bar z)}{|z+1|^2} \\[5px]
 &= \frac{4i \operatorname{Im}(z)}{|z+1|^2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z$ be $x+iy$. Then,

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{x-1+yi}{x+1+yi}=\frac{x-1+yi}{x+1+yi}\cdot \frac{x+1-yi}{x+1-yi}=\frac{(x^2+y^2-1)+i(2y)}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$
Since, $Im(\frac{z-1}{z+1})=0$ and $(x+1)^2+y^2\ne 0$
$$2y=0$$
Therefore, $y=0$. Hence, $f(x)=\frac{(x^2-1)}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}$, assuming $x \ne-1$.

Comment: @dxiv: Thank you for pointing my error. I apologize for late response because I was offline for a while. And also forgive me for these silly mistakes because I'm a half-blind chemist who like to explore his love for mathematics! :-).